Microsoft Lists Sharepoint Calculated Column IF AND
I'm trying to create a calculated column IF statement in Microsoft Lists and wondered if anyone could help please?
Column: Date
Column: Leaver Reason Test
Column: Status
Calculated Column to be the 'Status' column.
If the date column contains a date then I'd like the status column to say 'complete'.
If the date column is blank and the reason column includes the text 'Vol' then I'd like the status column to say 'TBC'
If the date column is blank and the reason column includes the text 'Inv' then I'd like the status column to say 'N/A'
I have tried this (below) but I'm probably way off - any help much appreciated!
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("Inv",[Leaver Reason Test])),[date]=""),"n/a"),IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("Vol",[Leaver Reason Test])),[date]=""),"TBC"),,IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("Vol",[Leaver Reason Test])),[date]=<>""),"complete","no idea"))))

Please try this formula:
=IF(ISBLANK(Date),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Vol",[Leaver Reason Test])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Inv",[Leaver Reason Test])),"no idea","N/A"),"TBC"),"complete")

Here is my test result:

